# C# Constantly renewing variable

Tags: c#, variables, global-variables

Hello I have a lot of variables as I mentioned below, but when I change the value of a variable that I refer to, this change is not adapted by the variables that use this variable.

```
 class PublicVariable
{
    public static string ActiveUser = UserInfo.Username;
    public static string ActiveUserPath = $@"{Application.StartupPath}\{ActiveUser}";
    public static string ActiveUserImg = $@"{ActiveUserPath}\User.png";
}
class UserInfo
{
    public static string Username = "-1064548"; //Working 
}
class Starting
{
    public void Login(string Username, string Pwd)
    {
        //After the user logged in.
        UserInfo.Username = "BruceWayne"; //Working
       /* Showing -1064548 = */ MessageBox.Show(PublicVariable.ActiveUser.ToString()); //Not Working.
    }
}
```

For simplicity of the code, ActiveUser is an example.
This code sequence is an example. The goal is to take the data from the database once.

Comment: Turn **PublicVariable.ActiveUser** variable to property like this: `public static string ActiveUser => UserInfo.Username;`

Comment: Why should it. You **assign** the **value** of `UserInfo.Username` to the `ActiveUser` field. When you later change the value in `UserInfo.Username` why should the value in `ActiveUser` change?

Comment: You never actually change the value of PublicVariable.ActiveUser.  When you define it in the class, you're not creating a pointer - you're assigning it a value.

Comment: Actually, you could make this work by adding a single character: `public static string ActiveUser => UserInfo.Username;` but I think your problem is more a lack of understanding here.

Comment: Thank you for your answers => did not work.  I tried a method that came to mind and did not work. How can I keep this up to date?

Comment: How did `=>` not work?

Comment: MessageBox.Show(PublicVariable.ActiveUserPath);

Comment: It's not working when I call it this way.

Comment: How did a method _not_ work??

Comment: Created. Thank you, but this time I call a different variable ActiveUserPath does not work here.

Comment: So... you once again use a property (with =>) or a method.

Comment: Yes. I added it. And it worked. However, he did not work on another variable using this variable.

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/PrJBz7.png It's the current one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem I'd suggest to use properties here. This would look like this then:

```
class PublicVariable
{
    public static string ActiveUser => UserInfo.Username;
    public static string ActiveUserPath => $@"{Application.StartupPath}\{ActiveUser}";
    public static string ActiveUserImg => $@"{ActiveUserPath}\User.png";
}

class UserInfo
{
    public static string Username = "-1064548"; //Working 
}

class Starting
{
    public void Login (string Username, string Pwd)
    {
        UserInfo.Username = "BruceWayne";
        MessageBox.Show (PublicVariable.ActiveUser.ToString ());
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use methods as well:

```
class PublicVariable
{
    public static string ActiveUser() => UserInfo.Username;
    public static string ActiveUserPath() => $@"{Application.StartupPath}\{ActiveUser()}";
    public static string ActiveUserImg() => $@"{ActiveUserPath()}\User.png";
}

class UserInfo
{
    public static string Username = "-1064548"; //Working 
}

class Starting
{
    public void Login (string Username, string Pwd)
    {
        UserInfo.Username = "BruceWayne";
        MessageBox.Show (PublicVariable.ActiveUser().ToString ());
    }
}
```

There actually isn't any major difference between properties and methods. However, *fields* (you used them) are different, as they don't update their value when the depending value changes. That means, as long as you don't have a reference to the other value (which would be the case for *objects*, like an object of your class `Starting`), the field value doesn't update.

Comment: Thank you for your response, my problem has been resolved quickly.